# PHP fixing undefined error with echo instead? But does not work

Tags: php, html, database, server, client

I am inserting and updating some values through a form with radioboxes and textarea.
Basically the query works fine but **if user does not select any radio boxes or leaves the text area empty**, I want an error message to pop up, instead of real php errors of undefined.... blah blah.

Sorry for this weird layout, but this text editor is super problematic with editing..

```
    $var1 = $_POST['var_1'];
    $var2 = $_POST['var_2'];
    $var3 = $_POST['var_3'];
    

    if(isset($_POST['button_name'])) {
    
    if(query1 && query2) {
      echo "Successfully inserted and updated"</h3>";
    } elseif(empty($var1) && empty($var2) && empty($var3)) {
      echo "not selected. Please Try Again"</h3>";
    } else {
      echo "failed to sent cause of query issue";
    }
} else {
    echo "nothing was selected";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First check if the variables are defined, then set them to their values:

```
$var1, $var2, $var3;

if(issset($_POST['var_1']) && isset($_POST['var_2']) && isset($_POST['var_3']) && isset($_POST['button_name'])) {
  $var1 = $_POST['var_1'];
  $var2 = $_POST['var_2'];
  $var3 = $_POST['var_3'];
} else {
  echo "Your custom error message";
}
```

Alternatively, you can use try and catch:

```
try {
  $var1 = $_POST['var_1'];
  $var2 = $_POST['var_2'];
  $var3 = $_POST['var_3'];
  $_POST['button_name'];
} catch {
  echo "Your custom error message";
}
```

Comment: What about the button?

Comment: You can do it in the same way.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked.

Comment: Glad to help! Consider marking the answer as accepted.

Comment: I tried to but users are lowering my score, not sure what their problems are with my question.

Comment: Probably you didn't perform a thorough search on your problem before asking.

Comment: That's my problem if I didn't, not theirs. But anyway huge thank you!

Comment: Just make sure next time you do some research. Stack Overflow discourages such behaviour.

Comment: Will do. Thank you